# Serialize Control to viewstate

Tags: asp.net, custom-controls, viewstate, user-controls

I'm writing a custom user control.  I feel like I'm doing this the hard way.

I understand that in order for my control's state to be preserved between postbacks, I have to save the data to ViewState.  I've done this with several fields in my User Control's class.

However, it seems very tedious.  Is there a way to make ASP.net save all the Serializable fields in my User Control to ViewState all at once when the page is done loading?

Answer (score 0):

I have a solution that you still need to adapt for your situation because this sample (re)stores all state of the control, also properties set by the asp.net runtime. Remember that Serializable is not settable on a property of field, only a class/struct. You can however create your own Attribute (ViewStateSerializable?) that you use to decorate the properties you want to retain during postbacks. Do remember that viewstate is going over the wire to the client so if you have a lot of it users might get upset....

```
protected override object SaveViewState()
{
    Dictionary<string, object > dict = new Dictionary<string, object>();
    foreach (var prop in this.GetType().GetProperties())
    {
        // here we decide what to save
        if (prop.PropertyType.GetCustomAttributes(
              typeof(SerializableAttribute), false).Length>0)
        {
            dict.Add(prop.Name, prop.GetValue(this, new object[] {}));
        }
    }

    var ms = new MemoryStream();
    BinaryFormatter bf = new BinaryFormatter();
    bf.Serialize(ms, dict);

    return ms.ToArray();
}


protected override void LoadViewState(object savedState)
{
    BinaryFormatter bf = new BinaryFormatter();
    Dictionary<string, object> dict = 
        (Dictionary<string, object>) bf.Deserialize(
        new MemoryStream((byte[])savedState));

    foreach(var kv in dict)
    {
        this.GetType()
            .GetProperty(kv.Key)
            .SetValue(this, kv.Value, new object[] {});
    }
    base.LoadViewState(savedState);
}
```